# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment. Proper use of tsplot in seaborn package for a dataframe?

Tags: python, time-series, seaborn

I cannot get this to work for my data so first I am trying a concrete example that is very similar. Here is the dataframe:

```
In [56]:

idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1990-01-01', freq='d', periods=5)
data= pd.DataFrame({('A','a'):[1,2,3,4,5],
                    ('A','b'):[6,7,8,9,1],
                    ('B','a'):[2,3,4,5,6],
                    ('B','b'):[7,8,9,1,2]}, idx)
Out[56]:
A   B
a   b   a   b
1990-01-01  1   6   2   7
1990-01-02  2   7   3   8
1990-01-03  3   8   4   9
1990-01-04  4   9   5   1
1990-01-05  5   1   6   2
```

So what I am hoping to do is plot a time series with a line for the central tendency among the variables (each column) for each observation (each day in the index), with a shaded area indicating the specified error estimator (probably just 95% ci) of the observations corresponding to each day.

I've tried this:

```
sns.tsplot(data, time=idx)
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-fa07e08ead95> in <module>()
      5                     ('B','b'):[7,8,9,1,2]}, idx)
      6 
----> 7 sns.tsplot(data, time=idx)

C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\seaborn\timeseries.pyc in tsplot(data, time, unit, condition, value, err_style, ci, interpolate, color, estimator, n_boot, err_palette, err_kws, legend, ax, **kwargs)
    253 
    254     # Pad the sides of the plot only when not interpolating
--> 255     ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    256     x_diff = x[1] - x[0]
    257     if not interpolate:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

The syntax for tsplot is:

```
sns.tsplot(data, time=None, unit=None, condition=None, value=None, err_style='ci_band', ci=68, interpolate=True, color=None, estimator=<function mean at 0x00000000044F2C18>, n_boot=5000, err_palette=None, err_kws=None, legend=True, ax=None, **kwargs)
```

So I am providing my data with the index as the time argument but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't think I need any other keyword arguments but maybe that is the issue.

If I do this with an array with dimensions (unit,time) instead:

```
sns.tsplot(data.values.T, time=idx)
```

I get the expected output (except without the timestamps are the xlabels):

[image]

But what is the right way to do this with a dataframe? I know it has to be in 'long form' but I'm not quite sure what this would mean for this specific frame.

Comment: UnboundLocalError looks like a bug to me . . .

Comment: I was afraid of that. Saw something similar that appeared to be fixed by installing the statsmodels package but I have this and just updated and retried the same code to be sure.

Comment: I'm no expert here, but it looks like this could happen if the groupby filter doesn't yield any results:  https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/timeseries.py#L201  -- The default condition for a dataframe is computed on line 108 if that's at all helpful... (Sorry, not much of a pandas guy myself...)

Comment: Good point. I think would be the issue given the line where the error occurs, but the default condition: `condition = pd.Series(np.ones(len(data)))` should result in all of the columns being aggregated, but it seems it can't find anything to aggregate. Maybe it has to do with there being a Multiindex

Comment: Yeah, I mostly pointed it out so you can experiment and see... Take your data and that condition and see if you can enumerate it the way they do... It might just be needing some small tweak to get your dataframe into the right format.  (But I still think it should be classified as a Bug that somebody ought to report ;-)

Comment: It may be a good idea to post a ticket at seaborn's github repo https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues.

Comment: I got the idea now but in my case its not really worth having to rework the data as opposed to just using an array like I mentioned previously

Answer (score 9):

I ended up figuring it out. Basically the first place I should have looked was [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/examples/timeseries_plots.ipynb) in the section titled, "Specifying input data with long-form DataFrames". What I had to do was this:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data.columns = np.arange(len(data.columns))
melted = pd.melt(data, id_vars=0)
```

The first line moves the DatetimeIndex into its own column and sets a default integer index inplace. Second line does the same for the headers except drops them out (I needed to do this because it doesn't seem to be possible to do the grouping with a multiindex). Finally we melt the data creating DataFrame that looks like this:

```
In [120]:

melted
Out[120]:
0   variable    value
0   1990-01-01  1   1
1   1990-01-02  1   2
2   1990-01-03  1   3
3   1990-01-04  1   4
4   1990-01-05  1   5
5   1990-01-01  2   6
6   1990-01-02  2   7
7   1990-01-03  2   8
8   1990-01-04  2   9
9   1990-01-05  2   1
10  1990-01-01  3   2
11  1990-01-02  3   3
12  1990-01-03  3   4
13  1990-01-04  3   5
14  1990-01-05  3   6
15  1990-01-01  4   7
16  1990-01-02  4   8
17  1990-01-03  4   9
18  1990-01-04  4   1
19  1990-01-05  4   2
```

Now after the DataFrame is ready I can use tsplot like so:

```
sns.tsplot(melted, time=0, unit='variable', value='value')
```

Which in my case is pretty much the same as if I did:

```
sns.tsplot(data.T.values, idx)
plt.xlabel('0')
plt.ylabel('value')
```

except if I added any conditions then tsplot would plot the other series and make a legend for me.

It would be nice is `tsplot` could at least plot dates as timestamps given the nature of the function. I think using the transposed array is going to be a much easier option for my application instead of using a DataFrame directly.